# Lyapunov function for $\left(\begin{array}{c}x'\\y'\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x-y-x^3\\x+y-2y^3\end{array}\right)$

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

I am looking for a Lyapunov function for the Nonlinear system
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}x'\\y'\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}x-y-x^3\\x+y-2y^3\end{array}\right)$$

I am trying with
$$V(x,y)=ax^n+by^m$$
But it doesn't work

Can you help me please?

Comment: This system is unstable in the first place.

Comment: This seems more like an oscillator. If you want to prove the existence of a stable limit cycle I don't think the Lyapunov approach is the correct one. Note that your Lyapunov function would be of use if you wan't to show stability towards the origin.

Comment: What is your objection to the standard $rr'=xx'+yy'=r^2-x^4-2y^4$? The terms $x^4+2y^4$ can be bounded above and below by multiples of $r^4$, these bounds then define circles that are useful to discuss the dynamic of the ODE system.